# Helix perpendicular to parametric equation

Tags: 3d, parametric

**What I am trying to achieve**

Firstly, this is just for fun and has no real world purpose.

I am trying to create a plot of a helix that is perpendicular to a curve. The helix is defined by a parametric equation (see below). 
The helix looks almost like I wanted it to (see plots below). However, there is something wrong with my equation that causes some imperfections in certain areas of the helix (see 2D plot).

**Plot: 2D view**

[image: 2D plot]

**Plot: 3D view**

[image: 3D plot]

**Equation for basic curve**

This is the equation for the basic curve that the helix should go around. This equation produces the desired plot. In the plot it is represented by the orange line.
$$
t=[0,2\pi[\\
r_1=5\\
\omega _1=1\\
r_2=2\\
\omega _2=7\\
r_3=0.5\\
\omega _3=500\\
\\
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  z\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  r_1\cdot cos(\omega_1\cdot t)+
  r_2\cdot cos(\omega_2\cdot t)\\
  r_1\cdot sin(\omega_1\cdot t)+
  r_2\cdot sin(\omega_2\cdot t)\\
  0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

**Equation with the helix**

This is the equation for the helix (represented by the blue lines in the plots). It produces mostly the curve that I am trying to achieve. However the helix is not everywhere exactly perpendicular to its centre (basic curve, see above). I think this is due to the red part of the equation.
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  z\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  r_1\cdot cos(\omega_1\cdot t)+
  r_2\cdot cos(\omega_2\cdot t)+
  r_3\cdot cos(\omega_3\cdot t)
  \color{red}{\cdot cos(\omega_2\cdot t)}\\
  r_1\cdot sin(\omega_1\cdot t)+
  r_2\cdot sin(\omega_2\cdot t)+
  r_3\cdot cos(\omega_3\cdot t)
  \color{red}{\cdot sin(\omega_2\cdot t)}\\
  r_3 \cdot sin(\omega_3 \cdot t) \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
**Question**

How do I need to change the red part of the equation in order to get a helix that is always perpendicular to its centre?

Comment: The word spiral is not the right scientific word. You should call it a (generalized) helix.

Comment: Besides, nice work [+1]

Comment: Yes, of course you are absolutely right 'spiral' is not the right term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us denote your original curve by a vector function $\vec{p}$. Thus,

$$\vec{p}(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
  x(t)\\
  y(t)\\
  z(t)\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  r_1\cdot \cos(\omega_1\cdot t)+
  r_2\cdot \cos(\omega_2\cdot t)\\
  r_1\cdot \sin(\omega_1\cdot t)+
  r_2\cdot \sin(\omega_2\cdot t)\\
  0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
With this notation, the vector $\vec{p}'(t)$ obtained by differentiating componentwise
$$\vec{p}'(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
  x'(t)\\
  y'(t)\\
  z'(t)\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
is tangent to the curve. Since your curve is contained in the plane, an easy way to obtain a vector perpendicular to the curve is to compute the cross product of $\vec{p}'$ with $\langle 0,0,1\rangle$. Using this, I obtained the unit normal vector
$$
 \vec{N}(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{r_1 \omega _1 \cos \left(t \omega _1\right)+r_2 \omega _2 \cos \left(t \omega _2\right)}{\sqrt{2 r_1 r_2 \omega _2 \omega _1 \cos \left(t \left(\omega _1-\omega _2\right)\right)+r_1^2 \omega _1^2+r_2^2 \omega _2^2}}\\\frac{r_1 \omega _1 \sin \left(t \omega _1\right)+r_2 \omega _2 \sin \left(t \omega _2\right)}{\sqrt{2 r_1 r_2 \omega _2 \omega _1 \cos \left(t \left(\omega _1-\omega _2\right)\right)+r_1^2 \omega _1^2+r_2^2 \omega _2^2}}\\0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

At this point, your spiral (or, helix, really) can be parametrized by the vector function

$$\vec{p}(t) + r_3 \vec{N}(t)\cos(\omega_3 t) + r_3 \langle 0,0,1\rangle\sin(\omega_3 t).$$

Using your parameters, this produces the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I just wrote to the OP, the word (generalized) "spiral" should be replaced by (generalized) 'helix".

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, I agree.

Comment: Very nicely worked out answer! Unfortunately I can't yet up-vote :-(